# C# - Determine which class an object should use on instantiation?

Tags: c#, oop, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 2 classes:  Entity and Control.

**Entity:**

```
public class Entity
{

   public float Rotate {get; private set;}

   readonly Control m_Control

   public Entity(float rot)
   {
     Rotate = rot;
     m_control = new Control();
   }

    public void Update(float time)
    {

            switch (m_control.Rotating())
            {
                case Control.Rotator.Right:
                    Rotate += time * 1.5f;
                    break;
                case Control.Rotator.Left:
                    Rotate -= time * 1.5f;
                    break;
                case Control.Rotator.Still:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;          
            }
     }



}
```

**Control:**

```
public class Control
{
        private Random rnd = new Random();
        private int _randomTurn;

        public enum Rotator
        {
            Still,
            Right,
            Left
        }

        public Control()
        {
            TimerSetup(); // Initialize timer for Entity
        }

 public Rotator Rotating()
        {

                switch(_randomTurn)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return Rotator.Right;
                    case 2:
                        return Rotator.Left;
                    default:
                        return Rotator.Still;
                }

            }

 private void TimerSetup()
 {
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(GameTickTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
 }


 private void GameTickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     RandomTurn();
 }


 private void RandomTurn() 
 {
    _randomTurn = rnd.Next(1, 4);
 }


}
```

Basically I want to make 'Control' class a base class and create two subclasses: PlayerControl and AIControl.  Currently both Player control inputs and AI control inputs are handled in the one Control class.

My dilemma is, in the Entity class, how do I determine what Control class the Entity will use?

The Entity class currently assigns the Control class like so:

```
readonly Control m_Control

public Entity(float rot)
   {
     Rotate = rot;
     m_control = new Control();
   }
```

I instantiate multiple Entity classes in another class like so:

```
public class Environment
{

readonly Entity m_entity;
readonly Entity m_entity2;

public Environment()
{
   m_entity = new Entity(90.0f);
   m_entity2 = new Entity(180.0f);
}
```

Is there a way for me to determine what Control subclass the entity will use when instantiating it?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your instance of `Control` via the constructor. Your `Entity` class will look like this:

```
readonly Control m_Control

public Entity(float rot, Control control)
   {
     Rotate = rot;
     m_control = control;
   }
```

Creating your `Entity` variables will look like this:

```
m_entity = new Entity(90.0f, new PlayerControl());
m_entity2 = new Entity(180.0f, new AIControl());
```

This approach is called dependency injection. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use generics:

```
public class Entity<TControl> where TControl : Control, new()
{
   public float Rotate {get; private set;}

   readonly TControl m_Control;

   public Entity(float rot)
   {
       Rotate = rot;
       m_control = new TControl();
   }
}

public abstract class Control {}

public class PlayerControl : Control {}
public class AIControl : Control {}

public class Environment
{

    readonly Entity<PlayerControl> m_entity;
    readonly Entity<AIControl> m_entity2;

    public Environment()
    {
       m_entity = new Entity<PlayerControl>(90.0f);
       m_entity2 = new Entity<AIControl>(180.0f);
    }
}
```

The constraints will ensure that the generic type derives from `Control` and can be instantiated using a parameterless constructor.